# Как работает этот код в opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь понять как работает opencart (а заодно и php). Но никак не могу понять один момент.

Вот, например, кусок код из контроллера `header.php`

```
class ControllerCommonHeader extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->model('extension/extension');
```

Что такое `load` в этом коде? Как я понимаю, это должен быть метод (или свойство) класса `Controller`. Дальше смотрю код класса `Controller`

```
abstract class Controller {
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct($registry) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function __get($key) {
        return $this->registry->get($key);
    }

    public function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->registry->set($key, $value);
    }
}
```

Еще больше вопросов. Получается, метода load здесь нет. Как я понимаю, при обращении к `load` должен срабатывать код `$this->registry->set($key, $value);`, но что он делает тоже не понятно.

Буду благодарен, если кто-то сможет объяснить как это все работает.

Comment: IDE установи полегче будет искать корни этих цепочек и почитай архитектуру MVC . На хабре очень хорошо описана

Answer (score 0):

При обращении к необъявленному свойству класса вызывается магический метод `__get`. В вашем случае этот метод внутри себя вызывает

```
return $this->registry->get($key);
```

Таким образом, в "регистре" `$this->registry` имеется ключ (если это массив) или свойство (если это объект) с названием `load`. Оно и возвращается при попытке обратиться к `$this->load`.

Каким образом заполняется `$this->registry`? Вероятнее всего, передается в конструктор. Но не исключен вариант когда ключи в него добавляются динамически, с вызовом метода `__set`.

Answer (score 0):

Это `MVC` так устроенно ядро `opencart` просто знайте что `$this->load` загружает файлы из `Model` или `view` или `Controller` например `$this->load->model('catalog/product');` так вот вызывается `model` -> `product`
который в своем контролере можете например получит информация о продукте:

```
class ControllerMyControllerMyController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->model('catalog/product');
        print_r($this->model_catalog_product->getProduct('40'));
    }
}
```